# RSpec is giving me a LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've recently been trying to run RSpec in a Rails application and I can't seem to get it to work. I've followed all the instructions and I still can't even get a simple test to run.

RSpec is in my Gemfile, and I've run `rails generate rspec:install`.

I have the spec folder set up with a simple model test. However, every time I try to run RSpec, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb. - Did you mean?
                    rspec ./spec/spec_helper.rb

Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- rexml/document
```

My user_spec.rb looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  it "tests my rspec installation"
end
```

I'm new to Rails so I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `gem 'rexml'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle` in terminal.